# Javascript, что такое хороший код?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер господа, после написания очередного кода на JS, мой товарищ сказал мне писать правильно код изначально, ибо пишу я по ходу мыслей, т.е за написание какой-то функции я могу изменить алгоритм дважды, трижды но суть и результат будут одни и теже, вопрос заключается в этом - как писать код правильно?
Как правильно спроектировать функцию на выполнении чего либо, вопрос может показаться глупым, и детским, но меня всегда терзает сомнение, что я где-то, что-то не так написал.

Например если взглянуть на материал (1) то там можно обнаружить на строке 8 такую вещь:

```
;(function (factory) {
```

Почему функция обернута в скобки, как ее вызвать?
Зачем перед скобками точка с запятой?

Меня интересуют подобные секреты в js, можете мне прояснить что к чему, объяснить как проектировать какие-либо функции а так-же посоветовать литературу для самосовершенствования в данном направлении?

Исходный материал
(1) https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js

Answer (score 4):

## Больше практикуйтесь

> Любой дурак сможет написать код, который поймет машина. Хорошие
>   программисты пишут код, который сможет понять человек. **Martin Fowler**

Если в общих чертах, то хороший код - это код, который понятен другому человеку с одного лишь взгляда, он простой и логичный, не содержит в себе нарушения принципов (**KISS, DRY, SOLID**), а следовательно гибкий. Вам удобно самому работать с подобным кодом, ведь его удобно читать.

**Дональд Кнут** говорил одну очень интересную вещь:

> Помните, что обычно есть решение проще и быстрее того, что первым
>   приходит вам в голову.

Когда пишите код, задавайте себе вопросы, как в будущем этот код может использоваться, что может быть расширено? Сколько времени потребуется на расширение такой архитектуры, а сколько на такое? Есть ли другие решения? Не пишу ли я костыль?

Всегда при написании задайте себе эти вопросы. Вы не сможете написать качественный код, если у вас нет опыта написания подобного кода.

Чтобы писать подобный код нужно очень много тренироваться и практиковаться. Вас не ударит озарение в один день. Плохой код, медленная работа - это все начальные этапы, ведь вы незнаете, почему текущая архитектура плохая и этому не научат в институте, вам нужно познать отрицательный и положительный опыт и на основе его, вы сможете понять всю истину. Открывайте код других библиотек, читайте правила, осваивайте книжки (**"Совершенный код" от Макконелла** или "**Рефакторинг и улучшение существующего кода" Фаулера**)

## По вопросам Javascript:

**1. Функция со скобками**

```
(function () {
    // код
})();
```

Это немедленно вызываемая функция в JavaScript (IIFE), т.е. синтаксическая конструкция, позволяющая вызвать функцию сразу же в месте ее определения.

**2. Точку с запятой используют для предотвращения ошибки при автоматическом объединении нескольких скриптов в один. Предположим, есть код и в нем есть ошибка:**

```
var a = 5
(function() {})()
```

Причём ошибку, которую найти иногда довольно трудно, да и сообщение о ней не самое дружественное: «TypeError: 5 is not a function». На самом деле, тут пропущена точка с запятой. Интерпретатор считает, что ему встретились две части выражения, между которыми пропущен какой-то знак. Эта ситуация часто встречается при автоматическом объединении двух скриптов в один.

Обычно для этого добавляют точку с запятой сразу перед такими блоками.

Comment: Обычно для этого добавляют точку с запятой сразу перед такими блоками. 
А если скрипты не объединяются, тогда js читает точку с запятой, как что? Это не ошибка синтаксиса считается? ...

Comment: @user190134 Интерпретатор, встретив подобный оператор, понимает, что предыдущее выражение закончилось и началась новая конструкция. Такой код: ;;;;;alert(2);;;;;;;;;alert(1);;;;;;;;; - будет работать и выведет 2 алерта. Некрасиво, но ошибкой синтаксиса не считается.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо чтения глупых цитаток и общих детских слов об успехе, советую обратиться к единственному правильному способу, без которого написание хорошего кода вообще невозможно; проверенному всеми авторами этих самых цитаток, это учение самому языку.
Все секреты уже написаны. Всё изложено более чем подробно уже множество лет назад.
 Литература от o'reilly, русский [портал-учебник по js](https://learn.javascript.ru/).
Разве этого мало? Что сдерживает? Мысль о том, что какие-то секреты языка лежат слишком глубоко и неразумно тратить слишком много времени на их изыскания, когда можно просто задать вопросик на SO и сразу же залить глаза истиной и финтов js (видимо, черпая из цитаток состоявшихся программистов, ага).

Короче: **секретов нет**. Просто берешь и пишешь код.
Чтобы писать хороший код, нужно его писать. Писать много и часто.
В принципе, можно заменить всё сказанное на предмет рисования, создания музыки или готовке еды - смысл будет один и тот же.
Просто практика, но просто - не значит легко (:

Answer (score -1):

точка с запятой исключает редкую ошибку которая может возникнуть

```
var b = 4     
(function() {})()
```

Точки с запятой не обязательно ставить в js в конце строк, некоторые этим пользуются, и как результат - ошибка (запусти в консоли). Функция объявленная таким странным образом является частью функционального выражения. Такая анониманая функция выполняется в потоке кода и не засоряет объект переменных. Тут подробнее http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/ru-chapter-5-functions/